# How to limit the offline data in cache of your browser coming from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore

My webpage keeps crashing when I have a huge dataset of documents.
when there are more than 100 documents retrieved, my application crashes due to memory crash due to no more space in the cache.
I don't want my webpage to crash on retrieving huge dataset.
I have used firestore as the database and firestore has a copy of the records locally, which crashes my application when there is too much data.

I have no idea how to approach this. As the official documentation does not specify a way to limit the offline data that can be stored in the cache.

I want to delete old data to make space for recent data in the cache.
I Want the recent 5 docs to be stored in the cache and rest ignored in offline as too much data in the cache is crashing my web page.
It would be very helpful if I could get a solution.
thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

In most environments it's best to let Firebase figure out its own cache size, but if it's necessary to explicitly restrict or expand it, you can set the maximum size of the disk cache with [`cacheSizeBytes`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings.html#cachesizebytes).

Comment: Thank you for responding. ideally, I want the firebase to figure out its own cache size but my application crashes when I create around 100 records and there is a memory crash cause the cache size is too much. This is what I am trying to avoid. any advice is deeply appreciated.

Comment: If the app crashes, find the exact error message and stack trace in your log output, and put those together with the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into your question.